# Automapper Conditional Collection Mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

Does anyone know a way (or a workaround) to conditional map a source's property in per map condition?

The purpose here is to conditionally map a collection of child objects based on a web service operation parameter.
Such as:

```
Parent GetParent(bool includeChildren);
```

So far the only feasible solution I found was to either create a wrapping class to add a boolean property, like:

```
public class ParentMapper
{
    Parent Parent;
    public bool IncludeChildren {get;set;}
}
```

Or to add directly an IncludeChildren property on the model source class, witch I really don't like because of the mixing of purposes.

A perfect solution would be something like:

```
TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, bool includeCollections);
```

But I don't think I'll get any luck with an efficient solution for that.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is nothing built-in allowing you to achieve this. You could do the following though:

```
var destinations = Mapper.Map<List<Parent>, List<ParentDto>>(
    sources.Where(source => source.Child !=null)
);
```

Another way of doing this is:

```
config.CreateMap<Parent, ParentDto>()
            .AfterMap((source, dest) =>
            {
                 if (source.Child !=null)
                 {
                     //do some stuff here
                 }
            });
```